# Finding the lowest point of a graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have 2 arrays, one with a range of values for the slope of a graph, and another one for the chi squared values
graphing them produces the following image

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.plot(maybe_slopes, chi2, c = 'grey')
plt.grid(True)
```

Slope vs Chi squared

[image: Slope vs Chi squared]

How can I find the slope corresponding to the minimum chi square without having to explore the whole grid of parameters? (since for this examples, there are 50 values per, but if I had 100 or 1000 values, there is more data to sift through)
For this example, the slope is close to -2
And the lowest chi squared is around 20K
Sorry, I'm new with matplot, and yes this is for a class project

Comment: `matplotlib` will definitely not be faster than `numpy` for finding the minimum.  You should not use plotting software for numerical computations.

Comment: @CoryNezin Gotcha. But if I was to do it via numpy, would the min functions work?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider your curves are stored in a NumPy array. If they are in a list, you can turn them into a NumPy array with `all_chi2 = np.array(all_chi2)`. Now you have your array of `all_chi2` with, say,  `m` rows and `n` columns, with `m` being the number of points in the chi vector, and `n` being the number of curves.

Because `all_chi2` is a 2-dimensional array, you are looking for the coordinate of the minimum value of this matrix `(m_min, n_min)`. This can be done with

```py
import numpy as np

# first, find the index of maximum on the unraveled matrix
arg_min = np.argmin(all_chi2)

# then find back the 2d indexes
m_min, n_min = np.unravel_index(arg_min, allchi2.shape)
```

There you go, you can extract the values that you pinpointed from the graph automatically.

Comment: Is there another way? A previous problem required me to do that already. Is there a way I can plot/find the horizontal asymptote of my graph since that's when it reaches the min vals? thanks for your answer!

Comment: I do not see any faster/easier implementation. Since you have the minimum and its coordinate, you can now plot it on the very same graph, unless I am missing the point :)

Comment: my machine learning class is just being extra. They basically wants us to find those indexes for the lowest values just from looking at the graph, and not sifting through the data. The question itself is confusing